# How to fix 'NoReverseMatch ' error in Django, Python

Tags: python, django

I got this error.

> NoReverseMatch at /reservation/ Reverse for 'reservation_remove' with
>   arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['reservation/reservation_remove/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

I don't know how to solve it.

This is my urls.py of reservation app.

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

app_name='reservation'

urlpatterns = [
     path('add/<int:nursery_id>/', views.add_reservation, name='add_reservation'),
     path('', views.reservation_detail, name='reservation_detail'), 
     path('reservation_remove/<int:nursery_id>/', views.reservation_remove, name='reservation_remove'),
     path('full_remove/<int:nursery_id>/', views.full_remove, name='full_remove'),
]
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import City,Nursery
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, InvalidPage
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout


def index(request):
    text_var = 'Start!!!'
    return HttpResponse(text_var)


def allCity(request, c_slug=None):
    c_page = None
    cities_list = None
    if c_slug!=None:
        c_page = get_object_or_404(City,slug=c_slug)
        cities_list = City.objects.filter(city=c_page)
    else:
        cities_list = City.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(cities_list, 6)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page','1'))
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        cities = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage,InvalidPage):
        cities = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)  


    return render(request,'service/category.html',{'cities':cities})



def allSitting(request, c_slug=None):
    c_page = None
    sittings_list = None
    if c_slug!=None:
        c_page = get_object_or_404(City,slug=c_slug)
        sittings_list = Nursery.objects.filter(city=c_page,available=True)
    else:
        sittings_list = Nursery.objects.all().filter(available=True)
    paginator = Paginator(sittings_list, 6)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page','1'))
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        sittings = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage,InvalidPage):
        sittings = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)    
    return render(request,'service/city.html',{'city':c_page,'sittings':sittings})

    def SittingDetail(request, c_slug, nursery_slug):
        try:
            nursery = Nursery.objects.get(city__slug=c_slug, slug=nursery_slug)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
    return render(request,'service/nursery.html', {'nursery':nursery})

def signupView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Customer')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form':form})

def signinView(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           username = request.POST['username']
           password = request.POST['password']
           user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
           if user is not None:
               login(request, user)
               return redirect('service:allSitting')
           else:
               return redirect('signup')
   else:
       form = AuthenticationForm()
   return render(request,'accounts/signin.html', {'form':form })

def signoutView(request):
   logout(request)
   return redirect('signin')
```

This is  my urls.py of project.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from service import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.allCity, name='allCity'),
    path('service/', include('service.urls')),
    path('search/', include('search_app.urls')),
    path('reservation/', include('reservation.urls')),
    path('order/', include('order.urls')),
    path('account/create/', views.signupView, name='signup'),
    path('account/login/', views.signinView, name='signin'),
    path('account/logout/', views.signoutView, name='signout'),
 ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += 
static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += 
static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my templates of reservation app.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block metadescription %}
    This is the reservation page. Proceed to review your items and place the reservation perfectry.
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
    Reservation - Travel Sitter
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if not reservation_items %}
        <div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <br>
                <h1 class="text-center my_title">
                    You don't have a resevation.
                </h1>
                <br>
                <p class="text-center">
                    Please click <a href="{% url 'service:allReservation' %}">here</a> to make the other reservation.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <br>
                <h1 class="text-center my_title">
                    Your reservation
                </h1>
                <br>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mx-auto">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
                <table class="table my_custom_table">
                    <thead class="my_custom_thead">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="5">
                                Your reservation
                            </th>
                        </tr>   
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for resesrvation_item in reservation_items %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{reservation_item.nursery.get_url}}"><img src="{{reservation_item.nursery.image.url}}" alt="" class="float-left rounded custom_image"></a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    {{reservation_item.nursery.name}}　
                                    <br>
                                    SKU: {{reservation_item.nursery.id}}
                                    <br>
                                    Price: ${{reservation_item.nursery.price}}
                                    <br>
                                    Total: {{reservation_item.quantity}} ×　${{reservation_item.nursery.price}}
                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                     ${{cart_item.sub_total}}
                                 </td>
                                 {% if reservation_item.quantity < reservation_item.nursery.stock %}
                                     <td>
                                         <a href="{% url 'reservation:add_reservation' reservation_item.nursery.id %}" class="custom_a"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle custom_icon"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'reservation:reservation_remove' reservation_item.nursery.id %}" class="custom_a"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle custom_icon"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'reservation:full_remove' reservation_item.nursery.id %}" class="custom_icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt custom_icon"></i></a>
                                     </td>    
                                {% else %}
                                     <td>
                                         &nbsp;<a href="{% url 'reservation:reservation_remove' reservation_item.nursery.id %}" class="custom_a"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle custom_icon"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="{% url 'reservation:full_remove' reservation_item.nursery.id %}" class="custom_icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt custom_icon"></i></a>
                                     </td>
                                     <td></td>
                                {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
                <table class="table my_custom_table">
                    <thead class="my_custom_thead">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Check out
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Please review your reservation before proceeding the payment.
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-left">
                                Your total is: <strong>${{ total }}</strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="mx-auto">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                      <script
                        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                        data-key="{{ data_key }}"
                        data-image="{% static 'img/atom.png' %}"
                        data-name="Travel Sitter"
                        data-description="{{ description }}"
                        data-amount="{{ stripe_total }}"
                        data-locale="auto"
                        data-currency="usd"
                        data-shipping-address="true"
                        data-billing-address="true"
                        data-zip-code="true">
                      </script>
                    </form>
                     <a href="{% url 'service:allReservation' %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block my_custom_button">Make the other Reservation</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my reservation_remove function of reservation view.

```
 def reservation_remove(request, nursery_id):
    reservation = 
Reservation.objects.get(reservation_id=_reservation_id(request))
    nursery = get_object_or_404(Nursery, id=nursery_id)
    reservation_item = ReservationItem.objects.get(nursery=nursery, 
reservation=reservation)
    if reservation_item.quantity > 1:
        reservation_item.quantity -= 1
        reservation_item.save()
    else:
        reservation_item.delete()
    return redirect('reservation:reservation_detail')
```

And this is my views.py of service app.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import City,Nursery
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, InvalidPage
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout


def index(request):
    text_var = 'Start!!!'
    return HttpResponse(text_var)


def allCity(request, c_slug=None):
    c_page = None
    cities_list = None
    if c_slug!=None:
        c_page = get_object_or_404(City,slug=c_slug)
        cities_list = City.objects.filter(city=c_page)
    else:
        cities_list = City.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(cities_list, 6)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page','1'))
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        cities = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage,InvalidPage):
        cities = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)  


    return render(request,'service/category.html',{'cities':cities})



def allSitting(request, c_slug=None):
    c_page = None
    sittings_list = None
    if c_slug!=None:
        c_page = get_object_or_404(City,slug=c_slug)
        sittings_list = Nursery.objects.filter(city=c_page,available=True)
    else:
        sittings_list = Nursery.objects.all().filter(available=True)
    paginator = Paginator(sittings_list, 6)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page','1'))
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        sittings = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage,InvalidPage):
        sittings = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)    
    return render(request,'service/city.html',{'city':c_page, 
 'sittings':sittings})

def SittingDetail(request, c_slug, nursery_slug):
    try:
        nursery = Nursery.objects.get(city__slug=c_slug, slug=nursery_slug)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    return render(request,'service/nursery.html', {'nursery':nursery})

def signupView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Customer')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form':form})

def signinView(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           username = request.POST['username']
           password = request.POST['password']
           user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
           if user is not None:
               login(request, user)
               return redirect('service:allSitting')
           else:
               return redirect('signup')
   else:
      form = AuthenticationForm()
   return render(request,'accounts/signin.html', {'form':form })

def signoutView(request):
   logout(request)
   return redirect('signin')
```

If I have to show the other code, please teach me.

Comment: Can  you show you're reservation_remove view?

Comment: `{% for rese*s*rvation_item in reservation_items %}` fix the typo in your template

Comment: I think here is your error `service:allReservation` there is no pattern in your `urls` with this name

Comment: I put a function of reservation_remove. Mr, Bajarunas, do I have to change here?

Comment: I added an other views it has a relationship. I fixed above things but I got same error again.

Comment: Maybe are you missing the namespace in the include of the reservation urls?

path('reservation/', include('reservation.urls')) -> path('reservation/', include('reservation.urls', namespace='reservation'))

Comment: Ｉ fixed my urls but I got the same error.  Please give suggestions to me.

Comment: Davit told you what the fix was.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you so much, everyone.